# Mac OSX-specific, Eclipse Keyboard Shortcut CheatSheet

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a comprehensive, Mac OSX-specific, Eclipse keyboard shortcuts 'Cheatsheet'.   In other words I need a one page document highlighting Eclipse keyboard shortcuts using an Apple keyboard.

I've been able to find some abbreviated eclipse cheatsheets for a MAC (less than 40 shortcuts) and I've been able to find a multitude of PC-specific keyboard cheat sheets for Eclipse.  Please do not reply with a PC keyboard cheatsheet or a mac cheatsheet with less than 40 shortcuts.

Thanks

Comment: Everything is listed in the Preferences in 'General > Keys'

Comment: Cmd+Shift+L will also list what's active in the current context. That's basically the definitive cheat sheet list for that moment.

Comment: @nitind Unfortunately, Cmd+Shift+L seems to have been overwritten by the "Quick Text Search" in Oxygen. I had to edit the key binding for that and change it to Cmd+Shift+F to resolve that conflict.